# How to ignore all files, but not sub-folders

Tags: git, commit, gitignore

I don't want to push **any files**, but only all the folders in git.

I have tried the following in my .gitignore file, but it is not working:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
/*
# Except for directories
!/*/
```

My folder structure is,

```
/project/uploads
                 -->thumbnails
                 -->original
                 -->croped
```

I need all the sub folders to go and neither files inside this "uploads" folder nor files in any  other subfolders.

Comment: Silly workaround: if all files have an extension, just ignore `/*.*` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Git does only track files. If you ignore all of them git has nothing to track. A possible solution is to add a `.gitignore` to each directory. You can create all the subfolders, add a `.gitignore` to each of them.

```
*
!.gitignore
```

This will then ignore all the files, but your gitignore files in the new directories.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there:

```
/*
!*/
```

There was just one / too much.
With this you can ignore all files but not the (non-empty) directories.

Comment: I have placed ..gitignore with content,

/*
!*/

^^ But didnot work. Its adding files inside the subfolder also

Comment: Oh you want to not only ignore all files that are not in subfolders but in general ALL files and just add the folders as if they were empty? To my knowledge, this is not possible in git since empty folders are completely ignored by default.